# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle doesn't work with svg wrapped in an object tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, dropdown

When I put my svg inline in the html and put a dropdown-toggle class in it, it works perfectly.
But when I wrap it with an object tag it shows the svg itself but when I click on it it doesn't show the dropdown menu, or shortly - it doesn't work.

Here is the code that works with the inline svg:

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left">
    <svg class="sidebar-icon-size notifications-icon dropdown-toggle" 
         data-toggle="dropdown" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 12.7 14" style="enable-background:new 0 0 12.7 14;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M6.1,9.5c-1.6,0.6-2.7,1.3-3.4,1.9c0.5,0.5,1.5,0.6,2.4,0.2c1.2-0.4,1.9-1.5,1.7-2.3c0,0,0,0,0,0C6.5,9.3,6.3,9.4,6.1,9.5
            M7.1,12.2c-3.1,1.1-5.6,0.5-5.7,0.2c-0.2-0.5,1-2.2,4.5-3.5c3.5-1.3,5.5-0.8,5.7-0.2C11.7,9,10.1,11.1,7.1,12.2 M10,5.8
            C8.2,1.9,7.3,0.5,4.3,0.5c-1.1,0-0.8-0.8-1.6-0.5C1.9,0.4,2.6,0.8,1.8,1.5c-2.3,1.9-2.1,3.6-1,7.8c0.4,1.7-1.1,1.8-0.5,3.5
            C0.7,14,4,14.5,7.4,13.3c3.4-1.3,5.6-3.8,5.2-5C12,6.5,10.8,7.5,10,5.8" />
    </svg>
    <ul class="topbar-menu dropdown-menu pull-right" style="width:200px;">
        <li>blabla 1</li>
        <li>blabla 2</li>
        <li>blabla 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the code that doesn't work with the wrapper object tag:

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left">

    <object class="topbar-icon-size notifications-icon dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" 
                            data="../../Styles/Icons/Notifications.svg"
                            type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    <ul class="topbar-menu dropdown-menu pull-right" style="width:200px;">
        <li>blabla 1</li>
        <li>blabla 2</li>
        <li>blabla 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried removing the dropdown-toggle class and the data-toggle attribute from the object tag so that they remain only in the svg file, I tried vice versa, to remove them from the svg file and put them only in the object tag, I tried when they are on both but it didn't work anyhow.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: What was the down-vote for...?

Comment: I assume twitter-bootstrap code simply doesn't work cross-document.

Comment: So the only way to handle this is to really dump all the ugly svg inside the code just to make it work with bs dropdowns? In addition, your assumption answers the case of putting the toggle class only on the svg file and removing it from the object tag, but if I put the dropdown-toggle on the object tag itself - then it's not actualy cross-doc because the object tag itself is inside the same html doc as the dropdown-menu ul, so even if we do assume that your assumption is correct, why doesn't it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the cause may be due to browser security restrictions related to clicking on `<object>` elements.

Try using an `<img>` instead.

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left">

    <img class="topbar-icon-size notifications-icon dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" 
                            src="../../Styles/Icons/Notifications.svg"/>
    <ul class="topbar-menu dropdown-menu pull-right" style="width:200px;">
        <li>blabla 1</li>
        <li>blabla 2</li>
        <li>blabla 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul, but I know it works with img but I lose the css control over the icon if I use img instead of object so I can't solve it with some pure css but have to use jQuery to replcae the img  with the inline svg so the css classes would be effective. Isn't there any workaround so that it could be solved with object or other wrapping such as img but without losing the css control over the svg?

Comment: CSS doesn't apply across document boundaries, so you can't style the `<object>` SVG with CSS anyway (unless there are CSS rules in the SVG document itself).

Comment: right, there are css classes in the path tag of the svg as you can see in the code I wrote above, there it has media queries and hover psuedo class and all the party, and it works with object but not with img

Comment: "there are css classes in the path tag of the svg". Err.. no there isn't

Comment: My mistake LoL, not in the path tag but in the svg tag, oopsi (svg class="sidebar-icon-size notifications-icon dropdown-toggle")

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I used `pointer-events: none` to the SVG element. I registered the click events to the parent element always (but not directly to SVG element)